# Add active class to an ng-repeat button with ng-click

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, angular-meteor

I want to:

> - Have a list which gets an active class when the user clicks on them using ng-repeat

I have done some coding:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
  <li ng-repeat="kit in kits"><a href="">{{kit.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

and the controller:

```
$meteor.subscribe('kits').then(function (){
  $scope.kits = $meteor.collection(Kits, false);
});
```

This returns a list of `kits` from the mongo database collection.

What's the best way to do this?

Thanks!

**edit**

I added the following code:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
  <li ng-repeat="kit in kits" ng-class="{'active': selectedItem == kit.name}"><a ng-click="selectedItem = kit.name" href="">{{kit.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

But the active class is not being removed when I click another `li`

**edit2**

here's the code to have the first one active but still having issues with them not removing the active class when I click on a different one that doesn't have the active class.

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills" ng-init="activeIndex = 0">
  <li ng-repeat="kit in kits" ng-class="{active:(activeIndex==$index)}"><a ng-click="activeIndex = $index" href="">{{kit.name}}</a></li>
</ul>
```

**edit3**

Here's the code I have now (still same result):

```
<li ng-repeat="kit in kits" ng-class="{'active': selectedItem == kit.name}" ng-init="selectedItem = kits[0].name"><a ng-click="selectedItem = kit.name" href="">{{kit.name}}</a></li>
```

Comment: Are you able to add an active property to Kit?

Answer (score 1):

You want only one active element at the same type or add class on each LI user will click?

with only one element selected at the time

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
  <li ng-repeat="kit in kits" ng-class="{'active': selectedItem == kit.name}">
    <a href="" ng-click="selectedItem = kit.name">{{kit.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

with multiple selections

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills center-pills">
  <li ng-repeat="kit in kits" ng-class="{'active': kit.active}">
    <a href="" ng-click="kit.active = !kit.active">{{kit.name}}</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi there, I tried your code but the active class is not being removed when I click another li, also, is there a way to have the first one active for the first time? thank you so much

Comment: Have you used first or 2nd version? For the default I guess you could use ng-init, use $index or set it manually

Comment: The first version of your answer, the one with `with only one element selected at the time` the second one just toggles it when I click again

Comment: I see the code, it works perfectly there, but when I try to implement it into my project, it has the first one active but when I click a different one, it doesn't remove the active from the others. I've edited the question `edit3`

Comment: If you use `ctrl as` notation then you need to change notation (check my codepen)